# Change keyboard shortcut to comment out lines in Spyder

Tags: python, comments, spyder, shortcut, personalization

I recently started using the Spyder IDE (Python 3.6) and I'm having some difficulties getting used to the keyboard shortcuts, which is complicated due to me using an azerty keyboard. The ctrl + 1 keyboard shortcut to comment out lines becomes ctrl + shift + 1 due to this (azerty keyboards only read numbers when holding the shift key). Therefore I was wondering if there was any way to change the keyboard shortcuts in Spyder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To change our shortcuts you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts`

and introduce the one you want to use.

Comment: I see how to change shortcuts there, but is it possible to add new shortcuts?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. A shortcut needs to be declared in Spyder's source code and exposed in the Preferences entry I mentioned above so users can modify it.