# Modify/create Spyder keyboard shortcuts `%clear` and `%reset`

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

**What I would like to do:**

I would like to modify/create keyboard shortcuts in Spyder to 1) clear the console (regardless of where my cursor is!), and 2) reset the variable explorer.

**What I have done so far:**

So far I am able to do these as follows:

1. clear the console:

- enter `%clear` in the console
- `ctrl + L` when my cursor is in the console
- `cmd + L` when my cursor is in the console

2. reset the variable explorer

- enter `%reset` in the console

I have been able to modify other keyboard shortcuts via  `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard shortcuts` as described in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787884/change-keyboard-shortcut-to-comment-out-lines-in-spyder). However, I haven't been able to modify/create the shortcuts for `%clear` and `%reset`.

**Software Versions/OS:**

I am running Spyder 5 with Python 3.9 on a MacBook OS BigSur 11.3.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Right now (May 2021) it's not possible to customize the `%clear` shortcut.

However, you can customize the `%reset` one by going to `Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts` and selecting the action called `reset namespace`, as shown below

[image: reset shortcut]

Comment: Hello.  Do you know whether it is possible to customise the %clear shortcut yet?  This would be very handy as it saves having to grab for the mouse, click into the console, press CTRL + L, then navigate back to the code pane.